# How to install pyqt5 in Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: pyqt5

While I am installing pyqt5 ,using the command  `sudo apt-get install python-qt5`,in terminal there comes a message with

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-qt5
```

What is the reason? Hope anyone will help?

Comment: The reason is that there is no `python-qt5` package in the Ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 6):

The correct package name is `python-pyqt5`.

So run

```
sudo apt install python-pyqt5
```